# Add extra cell in excel using alasql

Tags: export-to-excel, alasql

How I can add a cell above the headboard ? Thank you, great job

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nex6K.jpg)

My intention is to put multiple cells above the table using materials alasql

Comment: what have you tried so far? SO is not a place where someone code for you :)

Comment: i checked the documentation but couldnt find any thing over there in alasql documentation.
Attaching the jsfiddle link of what all i have achieved but the following wasnt able to achieve it at all cuz of lack of documentation.

https://jsfiddle.net/shupramanick/t5srttcc/

@hering